# In Jest, what is the difference between parallelizing via sharding and workers?

Tags: testing, jestjs

[Jest](https://jestjs.io/) recently released [the ability to shard tests](https://artsy.github.io/blog/2022/09/07/quick-tips-to-speed-up-ci/), allowing one to split the tests into multiple processes.

But Jest already runs tests in parallel with [multiple workers](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--maxworkersnumstring):

> In single run mode, this defaults to the number of the cores available on your machine minus one for the main thread. In watch mode, this defaults to half of the available cores on your machine to ensure Jest is unobtrusive and does not grind your machine to a halt

So, what gives? If Jest is already running tests in parallel, what help does sharding tests give? Is the parallelizing logic that Jest uses to split tests across worker processes suboptimal?

I may be getting *all* of this wrong, so please do not be afraid to correct me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharding is useful for splitting the test suite across multiple machines. For instance, in a continuous integration test runner, you might spin up two machines and have each work on half the files. Notably, the individual machines could be running the tests from that shard in parallel as well.

Here's what that looks like in GitHub Actions:

```
jobs:
  test:
    name: Jest Tests

    strategy:
      # We want all the matrix jobs to complete even if one fails
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        shard: ["1/2", "2/2"]

steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build assets with node ${{ env.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3

      . . .

      - name: Run Jest tests
        run: yarn jest --shard=${{ matrix.shard }}
```

In this scenario, if you have 10 test files, each job runner will execute 5.

Comment: Aha! So Jest parallelizes by splitting tests across workers on a *single* machine, whereas sharding distributes tests across multiple machines. Makes complete sense. Thanks!